# itemize, removing natural indent

Tags: lists, indentation, itemize

When you `itemize` items you usually have the entire list indented.  This is expected when you have a title or description of what you are listing.  I want to `itemize` but not have the natural indent.  I need to move all of the bullet points over towards the the leftmost edge of the margin like all other text you would enter.  How can I do this?

Comment: You might want to have a look at this question from stackoverflow (which really should have been moved here) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4968557/latex-very-compact-itemize

Comment: I actually tried that.  The answer with the most points was tried.  The itemize did become smaller but did not moved towrd the left margin at all.

Comment: @ArTourter Migration of older questions is deliberately not allowed (to avoid flooding sites with questions of variable quality). Thus is we want the same information here someone has to post it independently.

Comment: I found that using the solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2611276/latex-beamer-way-to-change-the-bullet-indentation) of `\setlength{\itemindent}{-2em}` was quite useful, and doesn't require loading another package.

Answer (score 348, accepted):

Any customization of a `list` environment, such as `itemize`, `enumerate`, etc, is most elegantly handled by the [`enumitem`](http://texdoc.net/pkg/enumitem) package.

You can use `leftmargin=*` locally,

```
\begin{itemize}[leftmargin=*]
  \item one 
  \item two
  \item three
\end{itemize}
```

or else you use

```
\setlist[itemize]{leftmargin=*}
```

in your preamble to make the change global.

[image: screenshot]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[showframe=true]{geometry}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\begin{document}

\begin{itemize}
  \item one 
  \item two
  \item three
\end{itemize}

\begin{itemize}[leftmargin=*]
  \item one 
  \item two
  \item three
\end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution! Just adding reference, this also works for the `enumerate` environment (:

Comment: When I try this, it works, however, it removes the space between the item and the bullet point:
*item 
when I'm really looking for...
* item

Comment: How does this work in amsart??

Comment: Unfortunately `leftmargin=*` doesn't work well if the bullet points are removed through `label={}` – there is still some additional space left. In this case, `leftmargin=0pt` seems to ensure that the items perfectly align with the boundary on the left.

Comment: Thanks, nice solution. Unfortunately, the [`enumitem`] environment seems to be incompatible with the [`enumerate`] package :-(

Comment: Sometimes it's harder than you expect : ``\setlist[itemize]{labelindent=0pt,labelwidth=0pt, labelsep*=0pt, leftmargin=!, style=standard}`` worked for me.

Comment: If used in a table, the first solution will raise the error: `LaTeX Error: Something's wrong--perhaps a missing \item.` (but the `\item` is there)

Answer (score 13):

`enumitem` package is a convenient tool. Since version 3.6, it offers a key called `left`, with which one can set two tabstops one for the start of label and another for the start of the text. For example in the following MWE:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\setlist[itemize]{align=parleft,left=0pt..1em}
%
\begin{document}
%
\begin{itemize}
\item first item
\item second item
\end{itemize}
%
\end{document}
```

`align=parleft` aligns the label to left in the parbox of size `\labelwidth`. `left=0pt..1em` means that the label (bullet symbol) begins *at* the margin, and the subsequent text (first item, second item etc.) start at `1em` from the margin.

Comment: Thanks for clear explanation about the parameters for `\setlist`.

Answer (score 7):

If you prefer not to use an additional package `\usepackage{enumitem}` in your latex file, try the following code

```
\begin{enumerate}
\itemindent=-13pt
\item 1
\item 2
\item 3
\end{enumerate}
```

It works perfect for me.

Comment: Perfect! `[leftmargin=*]` gave me an error, but this works nicely. Thanks.

Comment: This only unindents the first line of each item (inconsistent indentation for multiline items). Also, the `13pt` should not be hardcoded.

Answer (score 2):

For the common case where the label is set within an indent but the rest of the item is flush to the left margin like this:

`1. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Morbi sit amet dolor sed felis tempus blandit. Proin convallis pretium lobortis. Cras at ex eu leo pharetra fringilla.`

use `[align=right,itemindent=2em,labelsep=2pt,labelwidth=1em,leftmargin=0pt,nosep]`