# Indentation in enumerate/list

Tags: indentation, enumerate, enumitem

I'm trying to get rid of indentation in `enumerate`. The code below shows the indentation with `enumerate`, and then the only partial fix I could implement. With `enumitem` package I could avoid indentation on the 'count' line through `leftmargin=*`, but there is still indentation in the text. How could I fix that?

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\begin{document}

\blindtext

\begin{enumerate}
\item Case $a\in B$

\blindtext

\item Case $a\in C$

\blindtext

\end{enumerate}

\begin{enumerate}[leftmargin=*]
\item Case $a\in B$

\blindtext

\item Case $a\in C$

\blindtext

\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

Comment: this looks a lot like [itemize, removing natural indent](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/91124)

Comment: possible duplicate of [itemize, removing natural indent](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/91124/itemize-removing-natural-indent)

Comment: @cmhughes although I also voted for closing as duplicate, now I realize it it's not; `leftamrgin=*` alone (the answer in the alleged duplicate) doesn't do what is requested here.

Comment: @GonzaloMedina ok - I have retracted my vote

Comment: @cmhughes I didn't know one could retract the vote. How is it done?

Comment: @GonzaloMedina click close and it will give you the option to do so.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to make enumerate items align at left margin?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/29322/how-to-make-enumerate-items-align-at-left-margin)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This requires some manual adjustment, as you have to modify the argument for `widest` to be the widest number in the list. As the item numbers are right aligned, only the widest run to the margin, the rest are indented a bit.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{showframe}
\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}[label=(\roman*),widest=viii,itemindent=*,leftmargin=0pt]
\item Case $a\in B$

More text \setcounter{enumi}{7}
\item Case $a\in B$

more text
\end{enumerate}

\begin{enumerate}[widest=99,itemindent=*,leftmargin=0pt]
\item Case $a\in B$

More text \setcounter{enumi}{9}
\item Case $a\in B$

more text
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Watch out with this solution, as when the numbers have different widths (double or triple digits), they will hang into right margin.  See difference between this result and that of http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/29322/how-to-make-enumerate-items-align-at-left-margin

Comment: @cslstr Oops, you're right. Thanks for the notice. Don't have time to look do anything about it right now, will edit later.

Comment: Somehow the result is not preserved if count is set to romans:\begin{enumerate}[itemindent=*,leftmargin=0pt,label=(\roman*)]

Comment: @capadocia I edited my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe the `wide` option does what you want,if I understand well:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\begin{document}

\blindtext

\begin{enumerate}[wide]
\item Case $a\in B$\\
\blindtext

\item Case $a\in C$

\blindtext

\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

[image]