# Indent for itemize in IEEE papers

Tags: indentation, itemize, ieeetran

I would like `itemize` with no indent in a IEEE two columns paper. I already used:
the solution proposed here: [itemize, removing natural indent](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/91124/itemize-removing-natural-indent)

That is by adding `\usepackage{enumitem}` and

```
\begin{itemize}[leftmargin=*]
  \item one 
  \item two
  \item three
\end{itemize}
```

But it seems that with IEEE format I can not add :

```
\usepackage{enumitem}
```

at the begining of the paper, since when I compile it says:

> enumitem.sty: 45: LaTex Error: Command Label indent already defined, or name ind... illegal, see p. 192 of the manual.

What can I do if I would like to remove natural indent before items, in this case? I add that I would like the whole text that comes in the item has no indent not just the item's first line.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! The `IEEEtran` class is incompatible with `enumitem`.

Comment: Also, please consider adding a full minimal working example (http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that), so we can better help you.  Welcome to TeX.SE!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`IEEEtran`](http://ctan.org/pkg/ieeetran) completely redefines the default list environments. However, you can pass options via a newly-defined optional argument:

[image]

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{showframe,lipsum}% Just for this example
\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]
\begin{itemize}[
    \setlength{\IEEElabelindent}{\dimexpr-\labelwidth-\labelsep}% Wrapping of text beyond first line of \item
    \setlength{\itemindent}{\dimexpr\labelwidth+\labelsep}% identation for each new \item
    \setlength{\listparindent}{\parindent}% Restore regular paragraph indentation
  ]
  \item one 
  \item \lipsum[2-3]
  \item three
\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks, but I would like the whole text that comes in the item has no indent not just the item first line.

Comment: @BenBost: See the updated post.

Comment: The problem with `enumitem` [**got fixed**](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/279579/36835).

Answer (score 0):

#### IEEE journal formate two colomn bullet item.

**first add packages** \usepackage{enumitem}

```
\begin{description}
    \item[$\bullet$ The first approach -]
    \item[$\bullet$ The second approach -]
\end{description}
```