# Structure like itemize but with no indent

Tags: indentation, enumerate, paragraphs, itemize, ieeetran

I am writing an IEEE conference paper, and I am looking for a structure like itemize to list a bunch of properties but I would like to remove the indent from each item. As you might know I can not remove the indent of itemize with IEEEtran. I thought of using \paragraph but still it is redefined in IEEEtran. So I wonder if there exists some similar structure to use that requires no indent.

Answer (score 3):

You have to add the necessary options to the `itemize` environment. It might be easier with `enumitem`, but I don't think the copy editors would be happy if you load it.

```
\documentclass{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{showframe} % just for the example
\usepackage{blindtext} % just for the example

\begin{document}

\blindtext

\begin{itemize}[%
  \setlength{\labelwidth}{\widthof{\textbullet}}%
  \setlength{\labelsep}{3pt}%
  \setlength{\IEEElabelindent}{0pt}%
  \IEEEiedlabeljustifyl
]
\item First Item
\item Second Item
Second Item
Second Item
Second Item
Second Item
Second Item
Second Item
Second Item
Second Item
Second Item
Second Item
\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Nowadays You can load `enumitem` and use its additional parameters. In older versions of the [ieeetran](/questions/tagged/ieeetran)-class it was not possible due to incompatibility issues, but it got fixed with the most recent version.

**Changelog:**

> 10) Removed support for legacy IED list commands, legacy QED and proof
>       commands and the legacy biography and biographynophoto environments.
>       IEEEtran no longer defines or references \labelindent so as to
>       avoid namespace problems with list packages that define it.
>       Thanks to Sven Köhler for reporting the problem with enumitem.sty.

So update [ieeetran](/questions/tagged/ieeetran) to the most recent version **1.8b** and the following will work:

```
\documentclass{IEEEtran}

\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\begin{document}

\blindtext  

\begin{itemize}[topsep=0pt,parsep=0pt,partopsep=0pt,leftmargin=10pt,labelwidth=6pt,labelsep=4pt]
    \item First Item
    \item Second Item
\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

---

[image]

Comment: thanks, but \enumitem commands are redefined with IEEEtran that is why I asked this question. If I put what you propose in my text it produces compile error.

Comment: But do you have another ieeetran class than I have? It works for me. (current version is 1.8b)

Comment: yes,I use 1.7b , I tried with your version and it works.