# Removing natural indent for itemize in LyX

Tags: lyx, itemize

I would like to know whether it is possible to make an itemize list in LyX, with no indent.
By default, the itemize list has a space before the text, as in the following picture:

[image]

For LaTeX, the solution is mentioned in the following link: [itemize, removing natural indent](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/91124/itemize-removing-natural-indent). Is there any solution to do that in LyX without using LaTeX box in LyX?
Many thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to Document > Settings > LaTeX Preamble and enter the following:

```
\usepackage{enumitem}
\setlist[itemize]{leftmargin=*}
```

Then click "OK". This will only change the display in the compiled PDF, not the LyX display.

Comment: Many thanks for the response. It worked well.