# Properly position labels in enumerate or itemize

Tags: tables, lists, enumitem

Despite a lot of trying, experimenting with and without `enumitem` I cannot figure out how to shift labels in `itemize` to the left of the table cell in order to exploit the full cell width. Further difficulty is that I need to use `hyperref`, and it seems to interfere with vertical spacing in the table.

I would appreciate not only the working solution, but also a bit of explanation on how `itemindent`, `labelwidth` work. It seems to me that `leftmargin` does not have an effect either.

[image]

- I am inspired by [this beautiful answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/112376/71825).
- I am bound to use `xelatex`, `memoir`, `Arial` font, and the
  specified page geometry. That is why my minimal example is somewhat
  long.

---

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,onecolumn,openright,final,oneside]{memoir}
%===============================================
\settrims{0.cm}{0.cm}
\setbinding{0cm} 
\setlrmarginsandblock{*}{2.5cm}{1} 
\setulmarginsandblock{2.5cm}{*}{1} 
\checkandfixthelayout
%===============================================
\usepackage[dvipsnames,table]{xcolor}
\usepackage[colorlinks,linkcolor=blue,citecolor=blue,urlcolor=blue]{hyperref}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont[Ligatures=TeX]{Arial}
\newfontfamily{\headingfont}[Ligatures=TeX]{Helvetica Neue Condensed Bold}
\renewcommand{\tablename}{\headingfont Tab.}
\renewcommand{\thetable}{\arabic{table}}
%===============================================
\begin{document}
 \begin{table}[t]
  \rowcolors{1}{}{gray!10}
  \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}[t]{llXX}
    \arrayrulecolor{NavyBlue}
    No.&Duration& Methodological developments& Systems and Applications\\\hline
    % ======================= ======================= =======================
    1.& X months &
    \begin{minipage}[t]{\linewidth}%
      \tightlists
      \begin{enumerate}
      \item  Very long and complicated name 
      \item  Even longer and more complicated name
      \end{enumerate}
    \end{minipage}
    & Short name\\
    % ======================= ======================= =======================
    3.& Y months& Generalization towards some new scenario&
    \begin{minipage}[t]{\linewidth}%
      \tightlists
     \begin{enumerate}
     \item  Very long and complicated name 
     \item  Even longer and more complicated name
     \end{enumerate}
    \end{minipage}
   \\
   % ======================= ======================= =======================
   4.& Z months & Short name & Short name
 \end{tabularx}  
 \caption[]{\small Development plan}
\end{table}  
\end{document}
```

Comment: Have you seen this: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/91124/itemize-removing-natural-indent that should work in your table cells.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With use of the `enumitem` and `etoolbox` packages and not using `minipage` for `enumerate` list, you can achieve the following result:

[image]

**Edit.**
Now is considered comment Barbara Beeton's comment.

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,onecolumn,openright,final,oneside]{memoir}
%===============================================
\settrims{0.cm}{0.cm}
\setbinding{0cm}
\setlrmarginsandblock{*}{2.5cm}{1}
\setulmarginsandblock{2.5cm}{*}{1}
\checkandfixthelayout
%===============================================
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\newcolumntype{L}{>{\RaggedRight}X}
\usepackage[dvipsnames,table]{xcolor}
%===============================================
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont[Ligatures=TeX]{Arial}
%\newfontfamily{\headingfont}%
%    [Ligatures=TeX]{Helvetica Neue Condensed Bold}% I haven't this font
\renewcommand{\tablename}{Tab.}
\renewcommand{\thetable}{\arabic{table}}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\AtBeginEnvironment{table}{%
\setlist[enumerate]{nosep,
                    leftmargin=*,
                    label={\arabic*.},
                    before=\vspace*{-0.5\baselineskip}, % <---
                    after=\vspace*{-\baselineskip},}    % <---
                        }
\usepackage[colorlinks,
            linkcolor=blue,
            citecolor=blue,
            urlcolor=blue]{hyperref}

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}[ht]
\arrayrulecolor{NavyBlue}
\rowcolors{1}{white}{gray!10}
  \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}[t]{llXX}
No. &   Duration
        &   Methodological developments
            &   Systems and Applications    \\
    \hline
1.  & X months 
        &  \begin{enumerate}
      \item  Very long and complicated name
      \item  Even longer and more complicated name
            \end{enumerate}
    & Short name                    \\
%
3.  &   Y months
        &   Generalization towards some new scenario
            &   \begin{enumerate}
            \item  Very long and complicated name
            \item  Even longer and more complicated name
                \end{enumerate}     \\
%
4.  &   Z months 
        &   Short name 
            &   Short name
\end{tabularx}
\caption[]{Development plan}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Nice, but may I suggest using `\raggedright` (or maybe better, `\RaggedRight` from `ragged2e`, to allow hyphenation) in the paragraphed cells.  This example isn't bad, but sometimes the text is such that the spacing when there's more than one line is simply dreadful.

Comment: @barbarabeeton, this cross my mind, but now I can't remember why didn't do this :-(. Added to MWE.

Comment: Thank you! I would like to know why `\RaggedRight` is needed. It seem it just brakes the shorter item by putting the word name to the next line. Also, what is the purpose of `etoolbox` and why isn't it good to use `minipage` as in the linked post?

Comment: `RagedRight` is defined in the `ragged2e` package. It enable a smart way to make ragged/hyphenated text at right border. With it a text is better spaced in cells, `etoolbox` define `\AtBeginEnvironment`, which is used for formatting `enumerate` list in tables. Using `minipage` is fine, if you not use the `hyperref` package. With it is inserted some vertical space (this is probanly a bug)

Answer (score 1):

Here how to do it, without an explicit minipage, thanks to a command borrowed from an answer on this site and the `enumitem` package. I defined a `tabenumerate` list, with the relevant parameters:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,onecolumn,openright,final,oneside]{memoir}
%===============================================
\settrims{0.cm}{0.cm}
\setbinding{0cm}
\setlrmarginsandblock{*}{2.5cm}{1}
\setulmarginsandblock{2.5cm}{*}{1}
\checkandfixthelayout
%===============================================
\usepackage[dvipsnames,table]{xcolor}
\usepackage[colorlinks,linkcolor=blue,citecolor=blue,urlcolor=blue]{hyperref}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont[Ligatures=TeX]{Arial}
%\newfontfamily{\headingfont}[Ligatures=TeX]{Helvetica Neue Condensed Bold}
\newcommand{\headingfont}{\bfseries}
\renewcommand{\tablename}{\headingfont Tab.}
\renewcommand{\thetable}{\arabic{table}}
%===============================================
\usepackage{enumitem}
\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\compress}{\@minipagetrue}
\makeatother
\newlist{tabenumerate}{enumerate}{1}
\setlist[tabenumerate]{label=\arabic*., nosep, wide=0pt, leftmargin=*, before = \vspace*{-1.4ex}, after=\vspace*{-\baselineskip}}

\begin{document}

 \begin{table}[t]
  \rowcolors{1}{}{gray!10}
  \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}[t]{ll >{\compress\arraybackslash}X>{\compress\arraybackslash}X}
    \arrayrulecolor{NavyBlue}
    No.&Duration& Methodological developments& Systems and Applications\\\hline
    % ======================= ======================= =======================
    1.& X months &
      \begin{tabenumerate}
      \item Very long and complicated name
      \item Even longer and more complicated name
      \end{tabenumerate}
    & Short name\\
    % ======================= ======================= =======================
    3.& Y months& Generalization towards some new scenario&
    %\begin{minipage}[t]{\linewidth}%
% \tightlists
     \begin{tabenumerate}
     \item Very long and complicated name
     \item Even longer and more complicated name
     \end{tabenumerate}
   \\
   % ======================= ======================= =======================
   4.& Z months & Short name & Short name
 \end{tabularx}
 \caption[]{\small Development plan}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you. First of all, it was unexpected that your solution works even when `arraystrech` is used. Second, I read the documentation of `enumitem`, but never reached the convenience option `wide`. These equivalent definitions are really hard to guess. I have three questions: 1)Why is it bad to use minipage? 2) What is the purpose of `compress` for I see not differences? 3) Why also `wide` without any argument works?

Comment: @yarchik: 1) It is not necessarily bad *per se*, but it makes the code more complex. 2) `>{\compress]`  makes latex believe we've entered a minipage, and a list  at the start of a minipage has no vertical space above. However, it does not always work fine (and here I had to add a small negative vertical spacing via `before=`, maybe due to the change in `\arraystretch`). 3) `wide` without argument uses `\parindent`   as `\labelindent` by default, if I remember well.