# How to control margin size of custom itemize

Tags: indentation, itemize

I'm working with the Deedy Resume template, which provides a custom itemize environment:

```
\newenvironment{tightemize}{\vspace{-\topsep}\fontspec[Path = fonts/raleway/]{Raleway-Regular}\color{primary}\fontsize{10pt}{12pt}\begin{itemize}\itemsep1pt \parskip0pt \parsep0pt}{\end{itemize}\vspace{-\topsep}}
```

[image]

It's leading to something like a 4 space indent in front of each bullet point. I'm trying to reduce the width...to 2 spaces or flush against the margin, let's say.

I've found [itemize, removing natural indent](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/91124/itemize-removing-natural-indent?newreg=e6d1a22ebebd4ecd99049c920df3ecb9), but when I try adding `[leftmargin=*]` after `\begin{tightemize}` when it's actually used, and random places after `\begin{itemize}` in the `\newenvironment`, but never got it working.
Any suggestions? Never really worked with environment definitions to this extent.

Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! See if the standard `itemize`, with parameters set by package `enumitem` works with your template (try `\begin{itemize}[nosep, wide=0pt, leftmargin=*]\item ...\end{itemize}`).

Comment: \begin{itemize} works by itself, but when I add `[nosep, wide=0pt, leftmargin=*]`, `[nosep,wide=0pt,leftmargin=*]hihello` shows up on the page

Comment: Please post a minimal, yet complete, code showing the problem.

Comment: `\newenvironment{tightemize}{\vspace{-\topsep}\fontspec[Path = fonts/raleway/]{Raleway-Regular}\color{primary}\fontsize{10pt}{12pt}\begin{itemize}\itemsep1pt \parskip0pt \parsep0pt}{\end{itemize}\vspace{-\topsep}}` is the definition.

Then I use it like so: 
```
\begin{tightemize}
    \item 1
    \item 2
\end{tightemize}
```




In the simplified case, I'm using `\begin{itemize}[nosep, wide=0pt, leftmargin=*] \item 1 \item 2 \end{itemize}` it only shows up as "[nosep,wide=0pt,leftmargin=*]hihello"

Comment: But can't you use the equivalent itemize environment, with parameters set by enumitem?

Comment: Overleaf is showing an `Undefined Control Sequence` error when compiling, but the page is loading up the same between using \item and \enumitem

I did get some luck with `\setlength{\leftmargini}{10pt}`, which does it for everything and I'd be okay with that. Is there a nicer solution?

Comment: The nicer solution would be using enumitem. I'm not sure I was quite clear. `enumitem` is the name of the package. You still have to use the `\item` command, not `\enumitem`, which does not exist.