# Customizing itemize environment: removing the leading indent

Tags: enumitem

I'm trying to create a colon separated list with `\newlist` and `\setlist`. There's a leading indent I'm unable to get rid of. Would someone have a suggestion?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[showframe=true]{geometry}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\newlist{other}{itemize*}{1}
\setlist[other]
{%labelindent=0pt,
%  itemindent=0pt,
  label={},
%  labelsep=0pt,
%  parsep=0pt,
%  align=left,
%  leftmargin=*,
  itemjoin={{; }},
  after={{.}} }


\begin{document}
  \noindent    
  \begin{other}
    \item \lipsum[1][1]
    \item \lipsum[1][2]
  \end{other}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Also see:

[itemize, removing natural indent](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/91124/itemize-removing-natural-indent)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must set afterlabel to empty:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[showframe=true]{geometry}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\newlist{other}{itemize*}{1}
\setlist[other]
{afterlabel={},
 label={},
 itemjoin={{; }},
 after={{.}} }


\begin{document}
  \noindent
  \begin{other}
    \item \lipsum[1][1]
    \item \lipsum[1][2]
  \end{other}

\end{document}
```

[image]